# Magento 2 How to get rest API response as an object?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am getting rest API response as like below,

```
[{
"field1" : "val1",
"field1" : "val2",
....
}]
```

How do I get API response as object, without braces `[]`. It will return only one object every time, so there is no need of array.

```
{
"field1" : "val1",
"field1" : "val2",
....
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am dealing with the same issue. It works, but it's just annoying. I would prefer to consume a json object rather than an array containing the object.

Comment: I done by overriding webapi controller

Comment: Have you got solution?  We are looking for same solutions

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 Api returns json type (but it is possible to get xml instead of json).
You can't change it "like that" to object.

If you are using PHP to connect to M2 Api use [json_decode(string $json)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) PHP function to decode json.
You can use also [json_encode($value)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create json.

Comment: I can see Magento default api's responses are returning as `Object` instead of `Array(Object)`